# java tcp network delays

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, raspberry-pi, network-programming

I have a socket server written in Java which runs on an Raspberry Pi. I have a client which runs on a Windows machine and connects to the Pi and then sends a small ASCII string about every 30ms.

For the most part it works fine: however at times there is a significant delay in receiving the messages. I have tried transmitting using a Java app on the Windows machine and a app that is written in C++. They both exhibit the same behavior. I have pared down the Java server code (which runs on the Pi) to the bare minimum:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

class Network implements Runnable
{
    PrintWriter file;

    public Network()
    {
        try 
        {
            file    = new PrintWriter("/home/pi/logs/network.csv");
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        String command = "";
        
        System.out.println("Start Network");

        try ( 
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5802);
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
            ) 
        {
            int ch;
            
            System.out.println("Connected");
        
            long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            do
            {
                ch = inputStream.read();
                
                if (ch == '\n')
                {
                    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long dt = time - lastTime;
                    lastTime = time;
                    String msg = String.format("%d: %s", dt, command);

                    if (dt > 100)
                    {
                        System.out.println(msg);
                    }
                    file.println(msg);
                    file.flush();

                    command = "";
                    
                }
                else if (ch != -1)
                {
                    command += (char) ch;
                }
            } while (ch > 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println( "DriverStation: StartServer exception: " + ex);        
        }

        System.out.println("Disconnected");
        file.close();
        file = null;
    }
}
```

In the main, I start this running in its own thread:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start");

        Network network = new Network();

        (new Thread(network)).start();

        while (true)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a plot of the delay time between receiving messages. Note that if everything was perfect I should receive a message about every 30ms.

[image]

As you can see, there are times of significant delays (up to 1100 ms in this case). In this case there does seem to be some periodicity to it, but that is not always the case. Can someone give me some suggestions as to why this is happening and how to eliminate it?

Thanks.

I decided to try and rewrite the socket server (which runs on the Pi) in C++ instead of Java to see if that made a difference. Here is the result:
[image]

We see that the problem persists. However in this case there was only one instance where the delay was longer than 150ms or so (although it was more than 4 seconds). Once again the shorter burst of delays have a pattern which repeats every 60 seconds. What can be happening on the Pi that would generate this sort of repeating pattern?

Thanks again.

Comment: One improvement could be wrapping your PrintWriter inside an BufferedWriter and flushing only periodically like every second. I feel logging to your file system every 30 ms could be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However the logging is not the problem. I noticed the delays (lag) long before I put in the logging. The logging is there to help me isolate the problem. What can possibly be going on that would cause a 1 second or more delay?

Comment: You should definitely use `BufferedReader.readLine()` rather than rolling your own by reading one character at a time. You need to post the client code.

Comment: @Sync `PrintWriter` is already buffered. OP should just turn off line flushing in the constructor.

Comment: I have tried using readLine but it makes absolutely no difference. There is something fundamental happing at a low level with the tcp connection.

Comment: As I said previously, the logging is not the problem. I can remove the logging completely and it has no effect on the delays.

Comment: I can post the client code but I am pretty sure that is not where the problem lies. I added a time stamp to the messages and it is clear there is no delay in transmitting the messages as they are all spaced by about 30ms.

Comment: There can be delays at the sender after it gets out of the application into the kernel. Please post some client code as requested.

Comment: How is the client socket opened, does it disable Nagle?

Comment: I was not familiar with Nagle however upon googling it it seems that calling setTcpNoDelay(true) on the socket would disable it (correct me if I am wrong). Sadly, this has no effect on the result.

Comment: I will try and put together a minimal client version and post it. However be aware that I have also written a client using c++ and it behaves the same as the Java version.

Comment: Note that all of this is happening via WiFi. I have not tried a wired test to see if that also has the problem but even if it does not, that is not a solution since I need wireless.